# Default save-hook in mutt

Tags: configuration, mutt

I have multiple specific save-hooks defined for patterns. But for mail that doesn't match any of these, I would like to have a specific default. Right now mutt just takes the last of the defined save-hooks and uses that as a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a save-hook for `.*` at the end - this should be used if there are no save-hooks above it, that would override.

If that doesn't work, try to put `.*` *before* other hooks.

Comment: Setting the catch-all regexp before the other save-hooks worked. Thanks!